# remove duplicate column name before add it on DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Here is my code :

```
private void executerRequete(string requete, string description, string niveauAlerte)
{
    RequetesSQLResult res = new RequetesSQLResult();
    res.Description = description;

    string StSQL = requete;
    res.Results = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection _oConnection = new SqlConnection(_dataService.ParamGlobaux.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(StSQL, _oConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mat", _dataService.ParamGlobaux.StMatricule);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dd", dateDebut);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@df", datefin);


            _oConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row = res.Results.NewRow();
                    object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                    int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);

                    if (res.Results.Columns.Count == 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            res.Results.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(reader.GetName(i)));
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        row[i] = values[i];
                    }

                    res.Results.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(x.Message + ":" + x.StackTrace);
    }

    if (res.Results.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Results.Add(res);
    }
}
```

My problem is when the loop gets here :

> res.Results.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(reader.GetName(i)));

Everything works fine as long as I use only one table. When I use two or more tables, I get an error message "column [i] already exists".

Exemple :

```
SELECT * FROM Contrats X, Contrats Y
WHERE x.Avenant = 'CONTRAT' AND y.Avenant = 'CONTRAT' AND X.Matricule = Y.Matricule AND x.[Num Contrat] != y.[Num Contrat] AND
((x.[Date début] < y.[Date Fin] AND x.[Date Fin] > Y.[Date début]) OR
(x.[Date début] > y.[Date début] AND y.[Date Fin] IS NULL) OR
(x.[Date début] < y.[Date début] AND y.[Date Fin] IS NULL))
AND x.Matricule = @mat
```

=> error will be : "column 'Name' already exist", because it is read twice (one per table).

How can i keep only one column if they have the same name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you need both tables data?

if not - return only first table data

```
select X.* from ...
```

if yes - list all required fields in `select`, and give them unique names:

```
select X.Name as X_Name, Y.Name as Y_Name from ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check whether there already is a column with the same name before adding it:

```
string name = reader.GetName(i);
if (!res.Results.Columns.Contains(name))
    res.Results.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(name));
```

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you should not use `SELECT *` instead you have to use `SELECT Column1, Column2,.. Column n`.

Also its good practice to use `JOIN` to link two tables rather than `comma`

```
SELECT Column1, Column2,.. Column n
FROM Contrats X, Contrats Y
WHERE x.Avenant = 'CONTRAT' AND y.Avenant = 'CONTRAT' AND X.Matricule = Y.Matricule AND x.[Num Contrat] != y.[Num Contrat] AND
      ((x.[Date début] < y.[Date Fin] AND x.[Date Fin] > Y.[Date début]) OR
      (x.[Date début] > y.[Date début] AND y.[Date Fin] IS NULL) OR
      (x.[Date début] < y.[Date début] AND y.[Date Fin] IS NULL))
      AND x.Matricule = @mat
```